# How do one-sided Limits of a composite logarithmic function work at the edge of the Log's domain?

Tags: limits, functions, logarithms

Consider the following limit:
$$
\lim_{x\to2^{+}} \log_{5}(8x-x^{4})
$$
I understand that the limit of a composite function can be evaluated by first evaluating the inner limit and then using that result as the new limit point for the outer function.  My question is, how does the "one-sidedness" propagate through the calculation.  So using the above as an example:
$$
\lim_{x\to2^{+}}\log_{5}(8x-x^{4})=\lim_{u\to0^{?}}\log_{5}(u)
$$
Does the "one-sidedness" disappear? carry-over? does it depend on whether the inner function approaches from above or below? or what?

Comment: edited for limit arrows

Comment: First off $2^+$ is not in the domain of the log function above. Secondly, imo, the one-sidedness will depend upon how the inner function approaches.

Comment: "I understand that the limit of a composite function can be evaluated by first evaluating the inner limit and then using that result as the new limit point for the outer function", pay attention that this is only valid for continuous functions

Comment: @bigbang, the limit at $2^+$ can be taken, it's an endpoint of the domain

Comment: @StefanOctavian I am sorry but how? What do you say the left-hand side limit of $\ln x$ at $x=0$ is? As per my understanding, it shouldn't be defined.

Comment: @bigbang: As long as we are talking about real-valued logarithms, $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}}\log x$ does not exist as the domain of $\log$ is $\Bbb{R}^+$. So I agree with you.

Comment: @StefanOctavian: For all $x>2$, $8x-x^4<0$, and so $\log(8x-x^4)$ is undefined. Hence, the right-hand limit cannot be taken.

Comment: @Joe, oh, I see now, I didn't realize the function was approaching $0^-$ instead of $0^+$